# mkdir "max name length" vs pathconf MAX_PATH & MAX_NAME

Tags: linux, path, mkdir, pathconf

I'm wondering if there is a way to know the maximum size of a directory name mkdir can create. I empirically found that the limit on my version, 8.21, on an Ubuntu 14.04, is 1024.

```
$ mkdir $(python -c "print('x' * 1024)")
$ echo $?
0
$ mkdir $(python -c "print('x' * 1025)")
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘... (x repeated 1025 times) ...’: File name too long
```

According to pathconf (using a tool from pjd (a POSIX Filesystem Test Suite)):

```
$ # pathconf("/", NAME_MAX)
$ ./pjdfstest pathconf / _PC_NAME_MAX 
255
$ # pathconf("/", PATH_MAX)
$ ./pjdfstest pathconf / _PC_PATH_MAX 
4096
```

Any idea why the values are different ?

*Edit 1: Remove username from command line.*

Comment: The filesystem I'm currently playing with returns 0 for NAME_MAX, so pjd just goes :boom:.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with coreutils 8.21, and there's no limitation imposed by its `mkdir` utility on the length of directory names. In practice, there are limits on the length of argument lists passed to `execve` (usually a few megabytes), and the values of the `PATH_MAX` and `NAME_MAX` configuration values for the path.

On Linux, glibc's `pathconf` function determines `NAME_MAX` by calling `statfs` on the given path and using the `fr_namelen` value in the structure that's returned. So there may be one value for `/` and another value for your `pjdfstest` directory if it's in a different filesystem. In a comment, you said the filesystem is returning 0 for `NAME_MAX`, so it looks like it's not completely implementing the interface that userland code expects. You may have to look through the filesystem's source code to see how it implements filename and pathname limits.